# Keep prompt window open when running .exe (windows)

Tags: go

I have a quick script that is scraping some data from a text file and outputting some summarized results to the user. When this is ran on windows by double clicking the executable it just runs real fast and closes the command prompt and the results of the program cannot be seen. I know I can go into command prompt and run it from there. But, is there anything I can do for when a user double clicks the .exe file to run it to keep that window open so results can be seen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One trick is by waiting user input at the end of your application. Once user press any key, exit the application. The snippet:

```
func main() {
    //Your original code...

    fmt.Printf("Press any key to exit...")
    b := make([]byte, 1)
    os.Stdin.Read(b)
}
```

Comment: Nice this will do for now. Just wasn't sure if go had something built in I could use.